# Image of composition of functions

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have a function which is a composition $f=h\circ g$. Is it then true that $\textrm{im}f=\textrm{im}h$? I would say so. The values which $f$ actually takes need to be the same values that $h$ actually takes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values that $f$ returns are the values that $h$ returns when it is fed a value returned by $g$, therefore the values that $g$ returns *do* matter. The true identity is $\operatorname{im}f=\operatorname{im}\left.h\right\rvert_{\operatorname{im} g}=h\left[\operatorname{im} g\right]$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $h:Y\rightarrow Z$ and $g:X\rightarrow Y$ then $h\circ g:X\rightarrow Z.$ You are taking $f=h\circ g. $ Observe that the f takes the values x where as h takes the values g(x)!